# Как узнать, зашёл ли пользователь в приложение?

Tags: java, android

Работаю в AndroidStudioи, у меня есть форма регистрации. Подключена база данных FireBase. Когда пользователь входит, его переносит на другую активити. Но при повторном заходе в приложение, опять выскакивает вход. Как сделать так, чтобы программа проверяла, вошёл ли пользователь в приложение, и,если вошёл, сразу перекидывала его на вторую активити? А так же как сделать выход?

```html
package com.example.homeworkhelper;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AlertDialog;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;


import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.content.pm.ActivityInfo;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.TextUtils;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.example.homeworkhelper.Models.User;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnFailureListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnSuccessListener;
import com.google.android.material.snackbar.Snackbar;
import com.google.firebase.auth.AuthResult;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.rengwuxian.materialedittext.MaterialEditText;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Button btnSignIn, btnRegister;
    FirebaseAuth auth;
    FirebaseDatabase db;
    DatabaseReference users;
    String emailPattern = "[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+@[a-z]+\\.+[a-z]+";
    String phonePattern = "[+]+[0-9]";
    RelativeLayout root;





    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);

        btnSignIn = findViewById(R.id.ci);
        btnRegister = findViewById(R.id.perreg);


        auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        db = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        users = db.getReference("Users");

        root = findViewById(R.id.root_element);

        btnRegister.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                showRegisterWindow();
            }
        });
        btnSignIn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                showSingInWindow();
            }
        });

    }
    private void showSingInWindow() {
        AlertDialog.Builder dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        dialog.setTitle("Login");
        dialog.setMessage("Enter data");

        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(this);
        View sign_in_window = inflater.inflate(R.layout.sign_in_window, null);
        dialog.setView(sign_in_window);

        final MaterialEditText email = sign_in_window.findViewById(R.id.email);
        final MaterialEditText pass = sign_in_window.findViewById(R.id.pass);

        dialog.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int which) {
                dialogInterface.dismiss();
            }
        });

        dialog.setPositiveButton("Login", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int which) {
                if(TextUtils.isEmpty(email.getText().toString())) {
                    Snackbar.make(root, "Enter your E-mail", Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    return;
                }
                if(pass.getText().toString().length() < 6) {
                    Snackbar.make(root, "Password must not be shorter than 6 characters\n", Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    return;
                }

                auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email.getText().toString(), pass.getText().toString())
                        .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<AuthResult>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onSuccess(AuthResult authResult) {
                                startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, Main2Activity.class));
                                finish();
                            }
                        }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                        Snackbar.make(root, "Authorisation Error. "+ e.getMessage(), Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });
            }
        });

        dialog.show();
    }
        private void showRegisterWindow() {
        AlertDialog.Builder dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        dialog.setTitle("Check in");
        dialog.setMessage("Enter data");

        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(this);
        View register_window = inflater.inflate(R.layout.register_window, null);
        dialog.setView(register_window);

        final MaterialEditText email = register_window.findViewById(R.id.email);
        final MaterialEditText pass = register_window.findViewById(R.id.pass);
        final MaterialEditText phone = register_window.findViewById(R.id.phone);
        final MaterialEditText login = register_window.findViewById(R.id.login);

        dialog.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int which) {
                dialogInterface.dismiss();
            }
        });

        dialog.setPositiveButton("Check in", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int which) {
                if(TextUtils.isEmpty(email.getText().toString())) {
                    Snackbar.make(root, "Enter your E-mail", Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    return;
                }
                if(TextUtils.isEmpty(login.getText().toString())) {
                    Snackbar.make(root, "Enter your login", Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    return;
                }
                if(TextUtils.isEmpty(phone.getText().toString())) {
                    Snackbar.make(root, "Enter your phone number", Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    return;
                }
                if(pass.getText().toString().length() < 6) {
                    Snackbar.make(root, "Password must not be shorter than 6 characters\n", Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    return;
                }
                if (email.getText().toString().matches(emailPattern))
                {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Valid email address",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                else
                {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Invalid email address", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                if (phone.getText().toString().matches(phonePattern))
                {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Valid phone number",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                else
                {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Invalid phone number", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

                auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email.getText().toString(), pass.getText().toString())
                       .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<AuthResult>() {
                           @Override
                           public void onSuccess(AuthResult authResult) {
                               User user = new User();
                               user.setEmail((email.getText().toString()));
                               user.setLogin((login.getText().toString()));
                               user.setPass((pass.getText().toString()));
                               user.setPhone((phone.getText().toString()));

                               users.child(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid())
                                       .setValue(user)
                                       .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
                                           @Override
                                           public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
                                           }
                                       });

                           }
                       }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                        Snackbar.make(root, "Registration Error. "+ e.getMessage(), Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });

            }
        });

        dialog.show();
        }

}
```

Comment: Зачем выдумывать велосипед. Есть вход под аккаунтом. В сети полно инфы. Если что то не понятно отпишись, скину инструкцию

Comment: Что-то не понятно...

Answer (score 0):

Вот пример, как когда-то я это реализовал. Обратите внимание на метод onStart()

```
public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Button loginButton, registerButton, phoneLoginButton;
    private EditText loginEmail, loginPassword;
    private TextView forgetPasswordLink;
    private FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth;
    private DatabaseReference usersRef;

    private ProgressDialog progressDialog;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

        loginButton = findViewById(R.id.login_button);
        registerButton = findViewById(R.id.register_button);
        phoneLoginButton = findViewById(R.id.phone_login_button);
        loginEmail = findViewById(R.id.login_email);
        loginPassword = findViewById(R.id.login_password);
        forgetPasswordLink = findViewById(R.id.forget_password_link);
        progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);

        firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        usersRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users");


        loginButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                allowUserToLogin();
            }
        });

        registerButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                sendUserToRegisterActivity();
            }
        });

        phoneLoginButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                sendUserToPhoneLoginActivity();
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();

        FirebaseUser currentUser = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();

        if (currentUser != null) {

            sendUserToMainActivity();

        }
    }

    private void allowUserToLogin() {

        String email = loginEmail.getText().toString();
        String password = loginPassword.getText().toString();

        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(email) && TextUtils.isEmpty(password)) {

            Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Please enter your email and password", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else if (TextUtils.isEmpty(email)) {

            Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Please enter your email", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else if (TextUtils.isEmpty(password)) {
            Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Please enter your password", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else {


            progressDialog.setTitle("Sign In");
            progressDialog.setMessage("Please wait, sign in");
            progressDialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(true);
            progressDialog.show();

            firebaseAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
                    .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {

                            if (task.isSuccessful()) {

                                String currentUserId = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();
                                String deviceToken = FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();

                                usersRef.child(currentUserId).child("deviceToken")
                                        .setValue(deviceToken)
                                        .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                                            @Override
                                            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {

                                                if (task.isSuccessful()) {

                                                    sendUserToMainActivity();
                                                    Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Logged In", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                                    progressDialog.dismiss();
                                                }
                                            }
                                        });




                            } else {

                                String message = task.getException().toString();
                                Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Error: " + message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                progressDialog.dismiss();
                            }
                        }
                    });
        }
    }

    private void sendUserToMainActivity() {
        Intent mainIntent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
        mainIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
        startActivity(mainIntent);
        finish();
    }

    private void sendUserToRegisterActivity() {
        Intent registerIntent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, RegisterActivity.class);
        startActivity(registerIntent);
    }

    private void sendUserToPhoneLoginActivity() {
        Intent phoneLoginIntent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, PhoneLoginActivity.class);
        startActivity(phoneLoginIntent);
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Смотрите, чтобы пользователь каждый раз не вводил данные, Вам надо их куда-то сохранить, тот же sharedPref, о котором я писал в прошлой теме. Вам даже не надо сохранять его логин и пароль. 
К примеру, в пользователя есть логин + пароль + имя. Он проходит авторизацию, и если все окей, то создаете обьект `sharedPref` и добавляете в него статус `online = true`. Также можете добавить переменную `name` и впихнуть его имя. При выходе из приложения сохраняете все эти данные в обьект `sharedPref`, который создали раньше. А при запуске приложения проверять обьект `sharedPref` на наличия переменной `online`, и если она `true`, то получить еще другие данные, к примеру `name` и затем открыть 2ую Активити.
На деле будет так, что пользователь открыл приложение, началась вся проверка, это секундное дело, можете поставить анимацию загрузки или что-то в этом плане, и сразу открывается его личная страница (2ая Активити) и заполняете все его данные с помольщю обьекта `sharedPref`.

Если делать авторизацию через `Гугл`, то там такая же схема. Проходите авторизацию, а при других запусках приложения идет проверка -  проходил ли раньше пользователь авторизацию, если да - войти с помощью его учетной записи.

upd.

1. Создаете переменные.

   `val GOOGLE_SIGN = 123
   lateinit var mAuth: FirebaseAuth
   lateinit var mGoogleSignInClient: GoogleSignInClient`
2. В `onCreate()` вставляете настройки. По нажатию кнопки запускаете окно авторизации. И проверка, проходил ли раньше пользователь уже авторизацию.

   ```
       mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance()

   val googleSignInOptions = GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
       .requestIdToken(getString(R.string.default_web_client_id))
       .requestEmail()
       .build()

   mGoogleSignInClient = GoogleSignIn.getClient(context!!, googleSignInOptions)

   btn_sign_in.setOnClickListener {
       SignInGoogle()
   }

   if (mAuth.currentUser != null) {
       val user = mAuth.currentUser
       updateUI(user)
   }
   ```
3. Добавляете эти методы. Отвечают за саму авторизацию.

   ```
   fun SignInGoogle() {
   val signInIntent = mGoogleSignInClient.signInIntent
   startActivityForResult(signInIntent, GOOGLE_SIGN)
   ```

   `}`

   `override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
       super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)`

   ```
   if (requestCode == GOOGLE_SIGN) {
       val task = GoogleSignIn.getSignedInAccountFromIntent(data)
       try {
           val account = task.getResult(ApiException::class.java)
           if (account != null) {
               firebaseAuthWithGoogle(account)
           }
       } catch (e: ApiException) {
           e.printStackTrace()
       }

   }
   ```

   `}`

   ```
   private fun firebaseAuthWithGoogle(account: GoogleSignInAccount) {
   Log.d("TAG", "firebaseAuthWithGoogle:" + account.getId());

   val credential = GoogleAuthProvider.getCredential(account.getIdToken(), null);
   mAuth.signInWithCredential(credential)
       .addOnCompleteListener {
           if (it.isSuccessful()) {

               val user = mAuth.getCurrentUser()
               updateUI(user)
           } else {

               updateUI(null)
           }
       }
   ```

   }
4. Получение данных аккаунта пользователя.

   ```
   private fun updateUI(user: FirebaseUser?) {

   if (user != null) {

       currentUserEmail = user.email.toString()
       currentUserName = user.displayName.toString()
       currentUserPhoto = user.photoUrl.toString()
   }}
   ```

Для выхода из акккаунта используйте эту строку.

`FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signOut()`

И да, сама кнопка.

```
<com.google.android.gms.common.SignInButton
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
            android:layout_below="@id/name_account"
            android:id="@+id/signin_button_account"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    </com.google.android.gms.common.SignInButton>
```

Comment: Вот честно, опять ничего не понял. Можете, пожалуйста, в моём коде подправить? Могу вам свои контакты скинуть

Comment: Я немного позже кину пример с авторизацией через гугл.

Comment: Добавил пример выше.

Comment: И да, если я не ошибаюсь, Армен (автор поста выше), рассказал о способе, когда Вам в саму БД идут данные пользователей. В моем случае (через гугл), данные пользователя в БД поступать не будут и проверка будет проходить через другие сервисы. Если надо будет какие-то данные сохранить, придется самому добавлять их в БД.